# I'm getting null response from mockjax

Tags: jquery, response, mockjax

I have this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:        '/autocomplete',
    type:       'GET',
    dataType:   'json',
    success:    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

and trying to mock it with:

```
$.mockjax({
    url:            '/autocomplete',
    type:           'GET',
    responseTime:   50,
    responseText:    function() {
        this.responseText = {info: 'Merge !!!'};
    }
});
```

I'm getting NULL as a response from mocjax.

What am I doing wrong? How can I use the response function in mockjax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
responseText
```

it should be just

```
response
```

So, the correct version is:

```
response:    function() {
    this.responseText = {info: 'Merge !!!'};
}
```